# Allow discussion with employers (At least one?) when submitting a job application

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

When I post an application to a potential employer I can see my initial submit via the messages link from the jobs tab.  As it stands, the UI blocks any type of communication from the candidate to the employer.  This kind of makes sense as you guys probably do not want to harass / bother the employer with additional messages.  But there are cases where you want to message the employer due to you forgetting to add some information or you want to message them due to issues that you may have accidentally entered, it happens all the time.

The UI currently looks like this:

[image]

Can we please allow a certain amount like the job seeker is initially allowed to message the employer (3 times) for instance.  Something small...that way you aren't blocked if you need to say something to the employer.

Comment: For the person who downvoted I asked because it bit me!  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270890/apply-pop-up-does-not-make-it-clear-which-version-of-resume-will-be-attached

Comment: Remember that [voting is different on Meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta): **On posts tagged [tag:feature-request], voting indicates agreement or disagreement**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right that we're worried about spam.  This is the primary reason we don't allow this.  That said, there are two more points I'd like to make:

1. We are looking into possibly adding an "Oh shit!" timeframe to applications/messages where you can edit something out in the first X minutes of sending.
2. The other reason users would want to get back in touch with employers is because [they've been left in limbo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314031/didnt-get-the-job-or-did-i-but-in-limbo-what-are-you-guys-doing-to-pro).  This to me is the most important big problem for us to solve here.

If we can fix both of those, I don't think we'll need to up the number of messages that can be sent.

Comment: I'm glad you are at least thinking about this, currently I hate to say it but this process sucks.  Applied to three jobs and I'm still in limbo, the experience for me is not a good one.  I did this same sort of thing on a competitor site and I've gotten the opportunities, so something is clearly missing.

Answer (score 6):

Technically this does exist; kinda, sorta. There is an option the employer can set per listing to accept questions from candidates in limited scenarios. It's not perfect, but this is something we'd have to think hard about before we can commit to change.

Comment: Right but thats from the employer side, the applicant side is stuck wondering wtf to do at that point.