# Allow me to cancel my application on jobs

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

After applying for a job I read more into it and determine that it is not a right fit.  [Unfortunately I currently cannot message the employer in any way](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312461/allow-discussion-with-employers-at-least-one-when-submitting-a-job-applicatio).  If I go directly to a job listing it tells me the following:

[image]

But in no way can I retract or cancel my application.  This would be beneficial to the employer I think.  Instead of them thinking about me and scheduling time for a phone interview or an onsite interview it could come in the form of a simple email that the candidate decided he / she is no longer interested.

This would be very helpful.

Comment: Give a reason for declining at least!

Comment: Potential for abuse, most probably. Your proposal would allow one to easily flood an employer's mailbox with retraction emails.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Really?  The result is ONE single email to the employer.  And if Abuse is done handle the user not the process.  Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JonH I was typing my reply as you commented.

Comment: @JonH, nope, the result is one email per time you cancel your application. Malicious users could enter an tight apply/cancel loop that would result in several emails being sent, unless steps to prevent this are taken in the system.

Comment: Come on .. already...do I really have to provide all the implementation details?  If you cancel an application, you do it ONCE for one employee.  And further implementation details like limits could come into play.  This isn't money changing hands or any benefit so I highly doubt anyone really cares about doing such a thing.

Comment: I have uploaded my new resume, forgot to tap `save`, applied, and now i'm applied for the job with outdate resume. How do I cancel it?! Why you even ask to upload the resume instead of just asking for a link (so I could update it once at that link for all job websites)?

Answer (score 1):

I have to be honest, we have no plans to offer this functionality any time soon, so I'm reluctant to even put a status-deferred. It's not that it's a bad suggestion, it's actually more a technical issue. The part of the system that this suggestion touches is the messaging system which is a quagmire of technical debt and hacks; as well as requiring time from the design team.

I know it sounds simple, but I promise it's not easy for us to implement. There's also the situation of suddenly opening the employers up to an exponential amount of messages; something we'd have to think about.

Comment: Its one single message to the employer...why is it so difficult, a status field is put on an application.  Initial status is "In Progress".  If company accepts me it changes to "Accepted" if I retract its set to "Cancelled".  Not easy for us to implement?  This is not sending people to mars.

Comment: @JonH: Did you notice the part where he talks about the "quagmire of technical debt?"  I know that you personally have never worked for any company that has had to deal with this, but the rest of us have.

Comment: It might also help to make sending out applications less easy.  Accidentally touch-clicking the submission button on a touchscreen happens so quickly. A very simple captcha (not hard to read or process, just so some level of conscious interaction is required) would be perfect.

Comment: This really needs to be a feature, I just accidentally pressed the apply button on mobile like @polynomial_donut just mentioned and am now going to waste someone's time when then find out it was a mistake.