# Didn't get the job (or did I?!?!) but in limbo - what are you guys doing to proactively move employers to provide feedback?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

Much needed feature request, especially for the job seekers. Scenario: you've applied for a job via the jobs link on SO.  You wait, and wait, and wait, and wait, and continue waiting.  You search for this same job and the UI presents you with this:

[image]

The mail icon simply signifies that you've applied (ps: can we please get some more visualization / labels / tooltip for what this guy is).  In any event if you click on the job it says **Good luck you've already applied for this position**.  Great I applied about 3 months ago and haven't heard a single thing.  Once you apply you also cannot **Ask company X a question**.  You are left in limbo.

What are your plans on how you are handling this?  How can you effectively let the employer know: hey, we see in our database, 10 people applied for this job and you haven't contacted a single one of them in X amount of days.

Or on the other hand maybe they did contact someone and hired someone to fill the position but the 9 other candidates are left in limbo.

I think some intelligence needs to be implemented such that an email reminder goes out to the employers and says **Hey, we noticed this position was [filled / unfilled] would you like to automatically send an email to all of the applied candidates informing them of ....**.

Otherwise this experience kind of sucks for the job seekers.  There needs to be a more, shall we say, pleasurable experience between the candidate and the job seeker.  Right now it is very one sided (leaning more towards the employers).

Comment: It's worth noting that the vast majority of employers never bother to respond to the applications that didn't make it, so you're basically taking on the task of retraining the entire business community.  Even if you put something into Careers to remind them, it's unlikely that they would take the time to respond.  I still get leads from headhunters every day that I never respond to; it would simply take up too much of my time for no discernible benefit.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I agree with you, but hear me out please!  Not doing this will never change the state I am currently in (for myself, and for the website).  The website will continue to show me this envelope for as long as it may take.  A reminder email may be ignored by many, but maybe it won't be ignored by everyone?  Times have changed, companies have shifted, let's give folks the benefit of the doubt.  Yes there are still some ancient processes but this is SO jobs man!  I mean its SO Jobs man...I mean SO JOBS MAN!  If they got this far, they could answer a five minute email.

Comment: 150 applicants * 5 minutes for the 149...  so 1.5 days (12.416 hrs) to handle the rejection notices, just for that one position.  Perhaps a better approach would be to close the position as filled and have a system auto notify the 149 the position has been filled.  Or have the position "Time out" and send out notices of non-action by vendor

Comment: Given I rely on a 'timeout' after interviewing, that doesn't seem unreasonable.

Comment: @xQbert - or that...whose to say there were 150 applicants though, there really might not be that many considering some jobs do not allow for remote work.  So your example is a bit extreme, but your solution could be considered.  Plus xQbert it could be a MASS MAIL with one single email to all applicants.  I didn't really mean a one to one response for each person.  We are talking about a system here, notably jobs, the system could present a UI to allow sending to multiple personnel / all personnel all at once.  It could be a simple canned response.

Comment: @xQbert Doesn't have to be a personal note, just bulk email everyone that didn't make it. 1 * 5mins = 5mins. Maybe add a minute for building the list of recipients. A button to do this could easily be added for the employer part of JOBS. "Send a message to everyone that applied to this job" with a message field and a send button....

Comment: Maybe I've just spent too much of my life being a contractor! But if you apply for a job and you don't hear back from them. **you didn't get it** Simple as that. And the envelope to me - at least - says I've applied for this, so don't bother looking again (though an envelope seems more of a 'you've got mail' than 'you've already applied' sort of icon)

Comment: @xQbert, in reality, it doesn't take that long to send an email. You could even make it personal. I think I could do 150 emails in 4-5 hours. But you're right, automated would be best.

Comment: I think it's rather self-explanatory that no response = no job. *but*, if I were a job seeker I do think it would be rather cool to be able to tell, "Oh, they've seen my application", "They haven't even looked yet", "I was denied for lack of experience", "I was denied for lack of a particular skill", "I was not considered because they found a good candidate already" - I don't know how SO jobs looks from either end really, but if the system could be setup to *know* that kind of information, it would be a major helpful notification for job seekers compared to other systems out there.

Comment: @DoubleDouble - I like that too.

Comment: @MichaelB - That's not always the case.  My first job I got a response a MONTH after I interviewed.

Comment: A slight tweak to the SO site would actually take that "4-12 hours to send emails to non-accepted applicants" down to "2 minutes": Employer marks the job as "filled" and SO takes care of the notification via the site notifications already in existence.  If it wants to get even more fancy, there could be controls that allow the employer to individually mark a given candidate for why they were denied (per DoubleDouble's comment) although just knowing that the position was filled (vs. still open!) would be enough for most people.  The extra feedback is a "nice to have" but not essential.

Comment: Stack Exchange themselves took 2 months to respond my application (through careers), and I applied minutes or hours after it was posted. And I got an interview, it was not a rejection. Not that that was an ideal experience (no hard feelings) but things do happen within a company that can seriously delay even positive responses, so I'm not sure how the proposed solutions would handle that.

Comment: It's a no-brainer that there should be a way for employers to bulk-notify all applicants that a position has been filled. And the presumption above that "no response = job filled by someone else" is just wrong. Several times I've been on the hiring side, and a long delay happened due to various administrative or management bungles. Letting applicants continue to express interest every week or two would make total sense.

Comment: Any good solution to this problem would have the state of the posting available - "accepting resumes... initial screenings... interviews... shortlist... offers extended... closed" and a list of the applicants that are still in the running at each stage. This assumes that the careers-for-employers portal makes it easy for managers/hr reps at each stage to use their portal as the go-to place for who is still in the running and that it's regularly updated as it moves from stage to stage, and that users are notified when a stage moves and whether they made the cut.

Comment: @briantist Sorry it took us so long to get back to you...we have a stellar recruiting team, but our dev jobs get a *lot* of applications and it takes us much longer to get through them than we'd like. I know we suck at timely responses; we're trying to get better! (And we do get back to everyone who applies.)

Comment: @Laura this was for the SRE team actually, over a year ago, NBD. It sounded like there was a delay in looking at any applicants IIRC, but once the process got started it was smooth and everyone I talked to was pleasant. Anyway I didn't bring it up as a complaint. It seemed like there was a characterization in the comments that "bad" companies with "ancient processes" are the only ones who could have delays, and that "good" companies, like the ones who use SO jobs are likely to be the exception. Just offering a view that even great companies w/ good intentions have extenuating circumstances.

Comment: Perhaps the same gamification could be applied to employers as regular SO?  A job application is the same as a "question".  The employer gets points for "selecting a right answer" (i.e. the applicant).  Let us vote up and down job applications.  Perhaps the good behaving employers will rise to the top if they use SO as their primary means of filling jobs

Comment: It would be great if when looking at a company I could see if they respected past people by keeping them updated.   This my effect if I decide to put an application in.

Comment: I don't know exactly how it works for employers, but presumably they're paying a monthly fee to keep these postings up? You'd think the posting would be taken down fairly quickly after they fill the position in that case, but who knows.

Comment: If I had hiring someone for a job, I would not want to continue getting applications for it.  So I would certainly remove the ad.  Why shouldn’t that inform all past applicants that it had been removed?

Answer (score 21):

I agree with you; it totally sucks to apply for a job and never hear back, and then you're left wondering if they're just bogged down in applications and it takes them 3 months to get back to you, or if they filled the position, or if they processed your application and decided you weren't worth interviewing.

This issue has been on our minds quite a bit lately (especially mine as I'm planning some other changes to the employer experience of Careers). We think it's better for everyone if we can close the loop on jobs posted or introductions made via Stack Overflow. We really do want to make Stack Overflow the best place for developers to get a job, and that includes making sure you get answers even if the answer is "not this job" or "not at this time".

I'm not ready to commit to details of a feature or a specific launch date just yet, but my thinking is something along the lines of what was described in the comments: a mechanism that would notify candidates in bulk that they didn't get a job. We may ask for status updates on hiring for a certain position via email, or we may just do it on-site, but if a job listing expires or the company fills the job, we want to ask them "hey! Would you like Stack Overflow to notify the remaining candidates that this position is no longer open?"

We, Stack Overflow, would then take care of sending a message to any applications that hadn't received a response up until that point. One message, from us, rather than trying to force a hiring manager or recruiter to write a message to every person (even copying and pasting the same message to dozens or hundreds of applicants would take a long time).

One of the things that makes this tricky is that the speed of filling a position varies widely from company to company. We have a bit of research to do to figure out what the appropriate timing is for us to be poking companies for updates. I'd love to hear people's thoughts if *you* have expectations for what a reasonable timeframe is without a response, though, and we'll see if we can find something that matches developer expectations with the reality of companies' hiring processes.

Comment: My feeling is one month is too long, as I mentioned in the comments.  Maybe 3 weeks time to have some sort of response.  I cannot really answer this though as the factors that come into play are in your guys' hands.  For one thing, on the employer side if a job listing expires the company should have two indicators - one an email that comes in the form of "hello company the job listing X has expired" with two links.  One link is "yes position x was filled" and the other "no position x not filled :(".  Clicking the filled position would bring them to a nice ui asking to email remaining candadi

Comment: ...candidates and providing them with an editable canned response.  Maybe getting some feedback from them at this time as well to build upon the system.  The other link would allow them to renew the listing now as well as alternatively mass emailing the existing candidates if there were any.

Comment: PS: forgot to mention good luck with this.  I find this type of work very interesting and rewarding.  You guys are doing a great job of soliciting feedback.

Comment: You also have to worry about if the listing has expired and the company wants to renew the listing.  Does that mean all the candidates that originally applied be able to re-apply, does the company even want them to re-apply given they were not interested in said candidates...or?  This in itself needs a lot of thinking and logic, maybe worth another post...

Comment: @JonH Not sure yet what the appropriate amount of time is.  This is a HUGE problem though.  And I mean that we take this very seriously.  If all candidates can be assured their applications and messages do not fall into a black hole, and Stack Overflow ensures they'll have closure (positive or negative), than we'll have served developers in a pretty fantastic way.  We're not there yet, and we don't have any active projects along these lines, but I'd be mad at myself if we hadn't started to solve this in the first half of this year.

Comment: Also, only deferred because work here isn't starting immediately.

Answer (score 13):

As a job seeker, I'd consider this solved with the addition of [a simple "Don't show me this job" button](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312509/603977), preventing the post from showing up in any search list.

I made a recent application that was explicitly rejected, but they also hadn't hired anyone else yet. That's fine, it happens, and I appreciated them telling me, but I also **don't need to see that posting anymore**. The job continued to appear in my searches for a couple more weeks, but, as you say, with no interaction possible -- other than a twinge of frustration (I was pretty excited about that job).

A way to manually indicate "I gave up on this job" would, to my mind, neatly resolve this problem without [trying to change the entire world's hiring practices](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314031/didnt-get-the-job-or-did-i-but-in-limbo-what-are-you-guys-doing-to-pro?lq=1#comment290373_314031). Out of sight, out of mind.