# Can we have more information about where the team is going in terms of Jobs?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I posted this more than a year ago:

[Didn't get the job (or did I?!?!) but in limbo - what are you guys doing to proactively move employers to provide feedback?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314031/didnt-get-the-job-or-did-i-but-in-limbo-what-are-you-guys-doing-to-proa)*

And to this day I don't think I am seeing anything new (aside from UI/UX changes) in terms of the jobs on Stack Overflow. This area really suxors still!

Again I apply to a job, and I am left in limbo. There isn't any page where you see some sort of progress bar or any information that gives you the feeling to hang tight.

Did I get the job? - I don't know. Has the company viewed my application? - I don't know. Has the company moved my resume into a stack of considered applicants? - I don't know.  Did I even apply for this job? - I don't even remember, because I don't have a page that allows me to manage my jobs.

When can we expect something that is usable? The eye candy and user interface updates are appreciated, but Craigslist is still dirty but much more usable. For as much marketing as is being put out into the jobs page, how come nothing is being done to inspire me to continue looking for a job on this site?

Comment: To that very last one "Did I even apply for this job", you can find that: Click the envelope in the upper right -> Click "Sent" on the left nav panel -> Applications. This shows the cover letter you attached to the application. Other than that, I agree. More information about applications would be great.

Comment: How do you convince employers and HR folks to sign up for a system that requires them to update the status of every application like that? The bulk "This position has been filled" notice suggested on your previous question could work but I would think most HR people would balk at having to tell each applicant they're moving forward with their application at least twice (once in SO's system, once by phone/email/whatever).

Comment: How can You expect being told that You got the job by any means other than Your future employer...?? 
_"Has the company moved my resume into a stack of considered applicants_ , _"[...]progress bar"_   - You cannot expect **any** employer/HR to actually bother to update something like a 'status' or 'info' in dozens of outside system.

The only thing they do is:  1. receive the detailed and helpful application    2. if they are interested or they want to take it to the next level - contact the candidate _**directly**_

Comment: If You are not getting any response from the company - **that simply means they are not interested**.
... And very unprofessional btw, because one thing that every company owes any candidate is at least clear 1/0  _"NO"_ decision in a reasonable time. Explanation why - _no_, clear message that we are not interested - _yes_.
But that's not relevant here :-)

Comment: @andy Not every position wants you to apply through SO, hence there are listings that someone has applied to but SO doesn't know about it.