# What to do when applying for a job gives no response at all?

Tags: discussion, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs

The quality of jobs offered on Stack Overflow - and offered directly by the company hiring - is very good. That's why I keep looking at the listings!

However, there is one thing that seems not to work.

I've applied for a few positions on Stack Overflow, but on more than one occasion, there has been no response at all - apart from an auto email from Stack Overflow saying "Success! Your application for xxx engineer at Company yyy was sent"

I spend time filling in a nice cover letter, I have a CV, and I don't apply for jobs that are outside of my level of experience or I'd be totally unsuited for. I think I've done enough to at least get a one line response, "Sorry, we don't want to hire you". But on more than one occasion I've had no response at all.

If I was applying outside of Stack Overflow I would follow up the application to check what was happening. In the case of Stack Overflow there is no contact listed for the companies or roles so this isn't possible.

When I interview people or screen CVs I am sure to let the people who were not selected know. This is important because those same people might reappear wearing a different hat. Being straight with people is important and more so in the "small world" of specialists in your own field. The type of non-response I've outlined above is an indication of a poor attitude towards people.

I'm sure other Stack Overflow users would be interested to learn which companies are responsive, but there is no rating system for this.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is a common complaint and there's a number of things we're already doing today to mitigate:

- Employers with a high response rate get a badge displayed on their job listings:

[image]

- The "High response rate" badge is [searchable](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=stack+overflow&b=HighResponse).
- On the employer side, we're constantly educating our customers on the importance of a transparent and responsive interview process. For example, here's an article we've published on our developer hiring blog: [How to Keep Developers in the Loop During the Interview Process](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/blog/how-to-keep-developers-in-the-loop-during-the-interview-process).
- We've also built a number of employer features which aim at improving response rates. For instance, there are various in-product reminders on Stack Overflow Talent:

[image]

- Employers can even message and reject applicants in bulk. Not quite as nice as writing personalized responses, but still much better than no response at all:

[image]

(note that we do *not* allow bulk messages for outbound recruiting, i.e. when recruiters reach out to candidates first. This feature is only available for incoming applications.)

We currently do not offer any ability for the candidate to follow-up with the employer and check on the status of an application, but it's on our list of future improvements and we'll provide an update as soon as we have one.

Comment: And not a single thing has helped - got my job from Glassdoor recently.  Used and even helped report bugs on SO Jobs.  The experience was just not good.

Comment: Posted this back in 2016 - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314031/didnt-get-the-job-or-did-i-but-in-limbo-what-are-you-guys-doing-to-proa - to this day it had never helped.