# Does a SO user with low score stand any chance of landing a job through SO Jobs?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I am a SO user with a 1038 score. I am an experienced fullstack developer.

Over the years, I have applied for several jobs through SO but I have **NEVER** received any response from any of the employers. Is it because my SO profile has a low score? Do I need to get a "good" score before applying for jobs through SO? And in that case, what would a "good" score be?

I'd also like to mention that I don't face this problem at other job portals, where my profile usually gets good responses from the employers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that employers don't see your SO reputation unless they really go looking for it; there's no reasonable reason for them to consider it because someone with high rep could be a genius or just someone who wastes the better part of their day looking for easy questions to answer, or any other reason that could be both good and bad. If an employer *is* using your rep as a metric for sorting potential candidates, I don't recommend working for such an employer in the first place because they're making decisions based off of something meaningless.

Comment: I don't think that reputation or tag score plays a big role. I applied for several C# positions (which is my default work language for years) although never answering c# questions on SO. Applied for 4 positions, 3 responded which is almost the same percentage as for non SO job applications.

Comment: What matters a lot to me (I'm now in a position where I hire developers sometimes) is the CV. Yours shows the last entry for Nov. 2017. Is this the most recent thing you have?

Comment: I got a job through SO, and I had something like 100 rep at the time.

Comment: If the employer is any good, they will read your CV before anything else.

Comment: I'm a frequent editor on the main site, and I see plenty of good-rep folks who I would not dream of employing. They are variously lazy, stubborn, looking for free work, looking for a discussion - and they all have discovered how to pump rep points without being a diligent and self-reliant software engineer.

Comment: Dammit, Halfer! I thought you weren't going to tell anybody! Well. That's my career ruined.

Comment: 1000 rep isn't what I would consider low.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314031/didnt-get-the-job-or-did-i-but-in-limbo-what-are-you-guys-doing-to-proa - check out this question from 2016, this issue remains a problem. i don't think stackoverflow can make a dent in employer's hiring practices.

Comment: Considering there are users with over 5k rep who don't know how to write a question containing an MCVE, I don't think you or employers should care about SO rep.

Comment: Reputation doesn't make any difference at all. I've earned beaucoup reputation, and I still don't get answers back from most of the jobs I've applied to on the Careers site. The few times I do get an answer, it's "Thanks for playing. We won't consider hiring you because you do not have a CS degree."

Answer (score 70, accepted):

First off, I would like to thank you for your contributions to Stack Overflow and note that I wouldn't consider your 1,000+ reputation "low". In fact, you'll notice on your profile that this puts you right into the top third of users:

[image]

Now with that out of the way: I can't read the minds of employers advertising jobs on Stack Overflow, and it really depends on the specific jobs you've applied to and what the companies behind them are looking for.

But I will say that I highly doubt that the reputation numbers of job applicants are a particularly important factor for them. We do not feature that number very prominently in the employer UI. From anecdotal feedback, we know that other factors tend to be way more critical, such as years of experience and - for jobs which can't offer remote work or relocation / visa sponsorship - the candidate's location.

The fact that you've never received even a response is obviously disappointing. Unfortunately, this is still a [common problem and we're working on it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378709/what-to-do-when-applying-for-a-job-gives-no-response-at-all).

Other than that, personalized and targeted cover letters go a long way and will increase your chances of getting noticed. Good luck!

**UPDATE** Also, [Benjamin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1523776/benjamin-hodgson) just pointed out to me that he's answered a similar question a while back: [Do employers via Stack Overflow Jobs take your site reputation score into account?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350330/do-employers-via-stack-overflow-jobs-take-your-site-reputation-score-into-accoun/350331#350331)

Comment: I got *very* few responses and I'm at 50K+. Its not correlated to score

Comment: @BradleyDotNET that's definitely helping (and giving hopes) that you give your "high-rep" side of the story, but I wouldn't be so definitive about a correlation based on your sole experience. We would need some data crunching from Stack Overflow team (I think response rates VS reputation is not something that one can publicly query).

Comment: In perspective 1k _is_ quite low. In comparison, 2 months ago I registered on a low traffic SE site and my involvement so far has been very casual, not caring about rep at all. I have 1k reputation there after 2 months. If I had been participating in the busy Python and Javascript tags on SO with the same amount of effort, I would expect to have gained far more. Rep is a measure of activity and participation in active tags, more than anything else. That being said, people recruiting through SO will hopefully know this too.

Comment: how did you get this overal ranking as a percentage?  I can only see the default monthly rating on my profile and there doesn't seem to be a way to see different views.

Comment: @opa The ranking you see is whichever is the highest for the user you're looking at. And yeah, unfortunately we don't have a way to choose which one to see. You can glean that information manually by looking in the Users pages, or run a SEDE query to calculate it, though.

Comment: As both a user and an employer, I can assure you that low reputation on SO is definitely not a deterrent factor. As an employer, we are looking for much much more than just the points. High points also don't mean that we are going to immediately hire you. It's just based on who you are, so don't worry so much about the points.

Comment: Top 33% is not top 33% of active users. It's 33% overall, active+inactive.

Comment: @ThomasWeller you're right - updated!

Answer (score 43):

Reading with the eyes of a potential employer, I see you have a master's degree, a five year gap, and then two short-term work experiences.

That does not seem very inviting and I would not call that "experienced fullstack developer", not when I recall my own experience level after a year-and-a-half in the industry.

Now you probably did stuff in those five years. If you have any work experience to show, that might make an impressive CV. But you need to put it in there. People will not give you the benefit of the doubt if all they see is basically a blank page.

Comment: thanks @nvoigt! It's amazing how I overlooked my developer story. I have about a decade of experience and not even half of it is reflected there.

Answer (score 4):

It's curious that the whole discussion on this is based on reputation points alone and not the content of the profile. I haven't used the job search, but is it possible to link back to the actual profile if you choose to list your rep? Or, at least, can it be traced back?

At least in the UK, people can and will be fired for their social media posts. And that's after they get a job; a lot of cross-checks can happen before anyone gets a job - Facebook may be searched, for example.

It might be a HR person doing the searching but it's absolutely certain that if they brought a profile to me that they said they found here, the first thing I would do is try find the profile. Not for the reputation points but to see what code they were posting as answers.

I'm not in any way suggesting the content of your posts is insufficient (I haven't even looked), but it seems a bit off-the-point to be discussing a reputation score if the contents of a user's posts are viewable. *That* would be the measure, no?

Answer (score -41):

I think the jobs you have applied for were also applied to by many users with a much higher number of reputation points. Now the recruiters will see the score points and move on instead of giving a second thought to how wonderful you are in reality.

This might be the reason you might not get a call.

Comment: BTW, same applies for me

Comment: This kind of assumption will be true if all candidates are the same. Then sure, users with higher SO mark will be interviewed first.

Comment: I doubt many employers give a cr*p about imaginary internet points.

Comment: @Turnip if they don't, maybe that should be put in the job listing when you apply...knowing nothing makes the process even more obscure than if you applied directly

Comment: @kkarakk Expecting employers to make a list of things they don't care about and include it in the job listing is completely unreasonable. That list would be infinite, and Stack Overflow Rep is arguably just as (un)important to a job as knowing what social media you prefer. Should an employer who doesn't care about your social media use put "We don't care if you're a fan of Facebook, Reddit, MySpace, Instagram, ..."? I think not, and a "We don't care about your Stack Overflow Reputation" is just as useless. OTOH, if they *do* care, then that is something that should be included.

Comment: @DavyM  so then what is the value prop of using stack for jobs? it's the same as every other job site...mysterious and unknowable and employer focused

Comment: @kkarakk You seem to be convinced that Stack Overflow rep does somehow matter. It doesn't. And you believing that it will earn you job opportunities doesn't make the process any less mysterious and unknowable, it just means you think that it is more knowable because you think you know one of the metrics they consider. Unless an employer explicitly states that they consider your reputation when evaluating applications, there's no reason to think they do, regardless of your misconception about the value of rep.

Comment: @DavyM i apologize, my point is not that i'm saying stack rep matters, my point is that if employers are not forced to specify what they're looking for and are allowed to get away with vague "we need fullstack engineer with 3 years of react" then stackoverflow is no better than any other job site